# Name to a progression with the general term $a_n=a+d\cdot n(n+1)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, terminology, arithmetic-progressions

An arithmetic progression has a general term $$a_n=a+d\cdot n.$$ 
Working with a larger problem I arrived to an expression 
$$a_n=a+d\cdot n(n+1),\quad n=0,1, ...$$ 
with $a, d \in \mathbb{R}.$
Can you please help me with the terminology - what is the name of this kind of sequence?

Comment: This is a quadratic sequence.

Comment: Thank you @DMcMor , it is really helpful.